# matrix ring spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-category, ring-spectra

I am trying to understand matrix ring spectra. Apparently, I have two different definitions of those and I did not manage to show that they are equivalent - maybe they even are not in the general case.

Given a connective (commutative) symmetric ring spectrum $R$, we define the $k$-th space of $M_n(R)$ to be the following space of pointed maps
$$
[M_n(R)]_k = map_*(n_+, n_+ \wedge R_k)
$$
where the multiplication is given by 
$$
n_+ \to n_+ \wedge R_l \to n_+ \wedge R_k \wedge R_l \to n_+ \wedge R_{k+l}
$$
i.e. apply the first map, apply the second map wedge identity, then multiply in $R$. The definition is used in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405079v1.pdf) to define the algebraic $K$-theory of $R$ by considering $GL_1(M_n(R))$. The latter has the right homotopy type if $R$ is convergent (see the reference). Correct me if I am wrong, but this should be stably equivalent to $End_R(n_+ \wedge R)$, where we consider $n_+ \wedge R$ as an $R$-module spectrum in the obvious way.

My second definition works as follows: Take $R \times \dots \times R$ as an $R$-module with the "diagonal" $R$-action and define $M_n'(R) = End_R(R \times \dots \times R)$. At least if $R$ is semistable, the canonical map $n_+ \wedge R \to R \times \dots \times R$ should be a stable equivalence, but according to the answer to [my last question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173134/endomorphisms-of-modules-over-symmetric-ring-spectra) this is not enough to deduce that the endomorphism spectra are stably equivalent.

> Does the second definition make sense? Would it be enough to demand that $R$ is fibrant-cofibrant to get the equivalence? Is there a more general condition to achieve equivalence in this situation?

The way I see those two versions is that the space $M_n(R)$ contains matrices with just one non-vanishing column (or row?), whereas $M_n'(R)$ contains full matrices. Going over to homotopy classes of maps from a space into $M_n(R)$ adds the "elementary matrices" together (consider for example a loop running through two different copies of $R$). Thus, up to homotopy it should look like $M_n'(R)$.

Comment: I did not understand your first definition of matrix endomorphism but for the second one I would say it is better if to modify it by taking the wedge RvRv...vR instead of RxR...xR, in suitable model category of spectra RvRv...vR is fibrant-cofibrant.

Comment: @Fedotov: That would coincide with the first definition. $n_+$ is the set of numbers $\{1, \dots, n\}$ with an added basepoint.

Comment: Perfect, since RvR...vR and RxR....xR are stably equivalent, the first definition is more adequate because RvR.....vR is cofibrant fibrant as R-Module (in a good choice of model category) that is probably why the authors of your cited article have made this choice therefore End_R(RvR..vR) is a homotopy invariant object. The cofibrancy property is not well behaved with the cartesian product in the model category of spectra.

Comment: @Fedotov: The problem is that I have something that I want to understand and that maps nicely into the second definition, but not into the first. From what you say, I guess, I have to figure out if it also maps nicely into some cofibrant replacement of $R \times \dots \times R$, then.

Comment: RvR....vR is a candidate for the cofibrant replacement of RxR....xR.

Comment: @Fedotov: I know, but I can't map the space I am interested in into $R \wedge \dots \wedge R$ directly. Another question: What "good choice of model category" should I use?

Comment: Not the tensor product of R but RvR....vR (cuproduct i.e. "direct sum")! You can use EKMM model I guess.

Comment: @Fedotov: Sorry, I meant that. That was a typo.

Comment: In EKMM's category of S-modules, all objects are fibrant and $R\vee \cdots \vee R$ is thus cofibrant-fibrant. In most other models it is not, _but_ it has the special property that maps out of it preserve weak equivalences. This is basically because $Hom_R(R\vee\cdots\vee R,X) = X^n$, and finite products preserve weak equivalences in symmetric spectra, etc (they inherit this property from the categories of spaces or simplicial sets).

Comment: As a result, in most of these categories $End_R(R\vee\cdots\vee R)$ is a good model for the matrix ring.  By contrast, in most models $R\times\cdots\times R$ is _not_ cofibrant (with some small exceptions that mostly only occur when $R$ is the sphere or a group algebra).  As a result, taking $End_R(R\times\cdots\times R)$ is usually not going to provide the model you want.

Comment: The completely generic procedure would be to find a cofibrant-fibrant approximation for either $R\vee\cdots\vee R$ or $R \times \cdots \times R$ and use that.  However, that can be unwieldy in general and so it's very useful to have the more compact model that you described based on wedges.

Comment: @TylerLawson: So, for example $Hom_R(R \vee \dots \vee R, R \times \dots \times R)$ will be a model for $End_R(R \vee \dots \vee R)$, but not as a ring spectrum?